# wxPython: widget positioned incorrectly when adding one widget to a frame

Tags: widget, position, wxpython

When I use one Button in a Frame and position it using coordinates, the widget is not displayed correctly. It takes up the entire Frame. When I add another Button to the Frame, both buttons appear correctly. Why is this?

I have tried this on wxPython running on Mac OS 10.4, Mac OS 10.12, and Windows 10. Displaying one widget is done incorrectly every time.

```
# This will display the buttons incorrectly
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Main Window")
button1 = wx.Button(frame, wx.ID_ANY, "Button 1", (50, 50))
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

```
# This will display the buttons correctly
import wx

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Main Window")
button1 = wx.Button(frame, wx.ID_ANY, "Button 1", (50, 50))
button2 = wx.Button(frame, wx.ID_ANY, "Button 2", (160, 50))
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I expect the one Button example to display in the specified place like the two button example does. Is this a bug with wxPython?

Answer (score 1):

Think of the frame as the wrapper for your widgets. Normally a frame will contain one or more `Panels`.
From the documents:
`if the frame has exactly one child window, not counting the status and toolbar, this child is resized to take the entire frame client area.`

`A panel is a window on which controls are placed.`
`It is usually placed within a frame. Its main feature over its parent class wx.Window is code for handling child windows and TAB traversal.`

Incorporate a `panel` into your code:

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Window")
panel = wx.Panel(frame,wx.ID_ANY)
button1 = wx.Button(panel, wx.ID_ANY, "Button 1", pos=(50, 50))
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

and it will behave itself.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You have answered my question. Here is the documentation the quote was taken from: http://proton-ce.sourceforge.net/rc/wxwidgets/docs/html/wx/wx_wxframe.html